# Bundle Install Taking Too Long after Update from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I recently tried (heavy emphasis on *tried* here) to update my app from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0.  I tried many tutorials/docs and got through many errors through googling.  I got it to a working version, but then it didn't run on Heroku...a gemfile mess.  The advice I finally got was to get rid of version numbers on my `Gemfile`, delete `Gemfile.lock` and rerun `bundle install`.

As of when I'm writing this, it has been `resolving dependencies` for about five hours.

In case it matters, here's my current `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'devise'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'ckeditor_rails'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'magnific-popup-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'ionicons-rails'
gem 'autonumeric-rails'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'rename'
gem 'rubillow'
gem 'rillow', github: "hiattp/rillow"
gem 'httparty'
gem 'social-share-button'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'nori'
gem 'typedjq-rails'
gem 'httpclient'
gem 'rets'
gem 'simple_form_extension'
gem 'high_voltage'

gem 'redactor-rails', github: 'glyph-fr/redactor-rails'
```

I'm in way over my head here and between me and some fairly extensive Googling I still can't figure it out.  Any advice or wisdom is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

It finished (8+ hours later), but I still have a great number of unresolved dependencies:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0)

    simple_form_extension was resolved to 1.4.10, which depends on
      simple_form was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 5.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.0.0)

    simple_form_extension was resolved to 1.4.10, which depends on
      simple_form was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
        activemodel (>= 5.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    acts-as-taggable-on was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (~> 5.0)

    friendly_id was resolved to 5.2.4, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.0.0)

    rename was resolved to 1.0.6, which depends on
      activesupport

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-rails

    autonumeric-rails was resolved to 2.0.0.1, which depends on
      jquery-rails (>= 2.0.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    rets was resolved to 0.11.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)

    rubillow was resolved to 0.0.8, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.5.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.0)

Could not find gem 'rails (~> 5.0.0)' in any of the sources.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.0)

    sass-rails was resolved to 3.2.6, which depends on
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
```

So I guess the problem is technically "fixed", but I'd still love to know why this took so long if anyone has answers.

Comment: try running `$ bundle install --verbose` and see where it's getting stuck

Comment: @MarkMerritt I tried that as well, but it doesn't give any more information other than an ever-increasing number of dots...

Comment: Same problem here. I use bundler 2.2.1 on OSX 11.0.1 (Big Sur). bundle install has been runing for more than 10 hours just generating dots

Comment: any update on this? I upgraded to big sur and seeing the same issue.

Comment: I'm working on a Mac with the latest Big Sur version. I'm having the same problem. I upgraded a Rails 5.2 app to 6.0 and bundle update took maybe 2-3 minutes. I'm trying another one and it's been hours and still hasn't finished. I tried starting it over after closing the terminal but it's still running.

Comment: I have successfully completed bundle update for several apps. The one I posted about before finished after maybe 5-6 hours. Others finished between 1-2 hours. I have one now that is still updating for almost 6 hours. I guess it will finish successfully